Mapping a numpy matrix to a matrix of character strings
I have digital matrix consisting of 0s and 1s. Example:
p=[[1 0 0 1 0]
   [0 0 0 0 0]
   ...
   [1 1 1 1 1]
   [0 0 0 1 1]]

The rows of this numpy matrix signify time separated measurements of 5 element bursts of data. Each column signifies the channel of the measurement:
channels=[A B C D E]

I need to map channels on to p so I get:
q=[[A None None D None]
   [None None None None None]
   ...
   [A B C D E]
   [None None None D E]]

What is the most pythonic way to map p to q?

You can use a combination of np.tile to first expand out your string labels, then use np.where to select specific indices from p or set the result to None.
import numpy as np

p = np.array(
    [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
)
labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
expanded = np.tile(labels, (len(p), 1))
final = np.where(p, expanded, None)

print(final)


As @Mechanic Pig points out, broadcasting itself will fix this, so you don't even need np.tile.

np.where(p, labels, None) is enough, numpy's broadcast can handle labels well.

@MechanicPig  I started down a different approach and ended up with this but you're absolutely right. That's a bad mistake, thanks!
